# .NET Regex match/capture on one string and use captures in find/replace on different string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to implement a feature that regex matches various things in one input string and saves to named capture groups, followed by modifying a completely different input string using a regex replace that references those captures. Essentially the latter string is a compilation of data from various updating sources of which the first is potentially one.

I'm doing this within a .NET application so compiled solutions using the Regex object is available, but the match/replace pattern strings are provided by the end user at runtime (so I can't just do something specific with the MatchEvaluator overload, or combine the two input strings into one without being extremely careful).

I find this hard to believe, but I have yet to find any way to either retain matches/captures in the Regex instance or to pass them into a Replace operation (or any other means of persisting or accessing captures across atomic operations). As of now the best thing I have thought of is to do a Regex.Replace on the *replace pattern* with a MatchEvaluator that replaces e.g. "$1" with Match.Groups[1].Value.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have the best/only way, though you may want to consider supporting named captures references `${name}`.

Comment: @NetMage Yup, fully intend to do that. Maybe it won't be terribly tricky to do, but I would have figured there'd be a native method or existing extension that already did it. I guess this isn't such a common application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution and a sample use, doing as you suggested, a replace on the replace pattern. I chose to create dictionaries to store the replacement values, though this does cost some overhead.

First, some methods to create a `Dictionary` from a `Match` holding its groups:

```
public Dictionary<string,string> CaptureDictionary(Match m) => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().ToDictionary(g => g.Name, g => g.Value);
public Dictionary<string, string> CaptureDictionary(string src, string pat) => CaptureDictionary(Regex.Match(src, pat));
```

Now a method that takes a pattern string and replaces all reference patterns (either `$\d+` or `${\w+}`) with the corresponding value from a `Dictionary` if found (otherwise ignored):

```
public string Expander(string src, Dictionary<string, string> vals) {
    string expander(Match m) {
        return vals.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out var v) ? v : m.Value;
    }
    return Regex.Replace(src, @"\$(?:(?<var>\d+)|{(?<var>\w+)})", expander);
}
```

Now a method that applies `Expander` twice, first expanding captures from the match pattern and then expanding captures from the previous strings match pattern:

```
public string DoubleExpander(Match m, string pat, Dictionary<string, string> c1) => Expander(Expander(pat, CaptureDictionary(m)), c1);
```

Now you can write a method that takes a `string`, a match pattern `string`, a replacement pattern `string` and a capture `Dictionary` and applies it:

```
public string ExpandReplace(string src, string pat, string sub, Dictionary<string, string> vals) => Regex.Replace(src, pat, m => DoubleExpander(m, sub, vals));
```

Example usage:

The source string defines the value for three variables, `p`, `v`, `q` and the pattern extracts those values:

```
var s1 = "p = 7; v = 12; q = 15;";
var p1 = @"p = (?<p>\d+); v = (?<v>\d+); q = (?<q>\d+);";

var capture1Values = CaptureDictionary(s1, p1);
```

The second replacement uses those capture variable values to expand them in an expression string:

```
var s2 = "x = p+v*q";
var pat2 = @"([pvq])";
var sub2 = @"${$1}";

var ans = ExpandReplace(s2, pat2, sub2, capture1Values);
```

NOTE: I normally prefer extension methods, so this is the condensed code as extensions:

```
public static class ReplaceExt {
    public static Dictionary<string, string> CaptureDictionaryFrom(this string src, string pat) => Regex.Match(src, pat).ToCaptureDictionary();
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ToCaptureDictionary(this Match m) => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().ToDictionary(g => g.Name, g => g.Value);
    public static string Expand(this string src, Dictionary<string, string> vals) => Regex.Replace(src, @"\$(?:(?<var>\d+)|{(?<var>\w+)})", m => vals.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out var v) ? v : m.Value);
    public static string ExpandReplace(this string src, string pat, string sub, Dictionary<string, string> vals) => Regex.Replace(src, pat, m => sub.Expand(m.ToCaptureDictionary()).Expand(vals));
}
```

Used similarly to before:

```
var s1 = "p = 7; v = 12; q = 15;";
var p1 = @"p = (?<p>\d+); v = (?<v>\d+); q = (?<q>\d+);";
var capture1Values = s1.CaptureDictionaryFrom(p1);

var s2 = "x = p+v*q";
var pat2 = @"([pvq])";
var sub2 = @"${$1}";

var ans = s2.ExpandReplace(pat2, sub2, capture1Values);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm relatively inexperience in C#/regex, so this helped me. I did choose to go a slightly different direction as noted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to regular expressions and it occurred to me when I got into coding this why it's a bespoken solution - because even within the same string capture groups don't persist across matches.

I went off NetMage's suggestion but implemented it as an extension method of Regex.Replace. It seems to me this is essentially providing the option to override the available match data for each match in the replace during substitution with an instance that is passed in, so I did it for a single match only (against the first document as a whole) and may notify the user if their first regex yielded multiple matches since only one will be used to prevent conflicts. Perhaps it'd be more intuitive if the parameter type were a CaptureCollection instead.

In the end I will probably also implement the remaining capture group options (e.g. $$, $', etc.) for thoroughness.

```
public static class RegexEx
{
    public static string Replace(this Regex inst, string input, string replacement, Match match)
    {
        replacement = Regex.Replace(replacement, @"(?<!\\)\$(?:(?<Name>\d+)|{(?<Name>\w+)})", m =>
        {
            return match.Groups[m.Groups["Name"].Value].Success ?
                match.Groups[m.Groups["Name"].Value].Value : m.Value;
        });

        return inst.Replace(input, replacement);
    }
}
```